# Process RAM usage

Tags: java, linux

Just a question that i wasn't able to find an answer too after a lot of searching.

Can a single instance of a java software use more than 10GB of ram on a server that has more than 128GB of RAM installed and still run fine without any issues? Or are there any limits on memory usage of a single instance of process.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum heap size for the Java Virtual Machine will most likely be constrained by your OS. Theoretically, if you have a 64-bit machine, you can allocate the JVM a heap size of 2^64. Since you have 128GB of memory, this is most likely your upper limit. Although, without knowing what your OS is, other constraints may arise.

edit: this link contains a guide to helping you setup your memory limits for your JVM on some different operating systems -> [Guide](https://docs.bmc.com/docs/display/public/bcmco95/Managing+Maximum+Memory+values+for+a+Java+Virtual+Machine)